# What mobile browsers should I be testing my mobile web pages with?

Tags: testing, cross-browser, mobile-website

Time sensitive question I realize, but I haven't been able to find a good resource detailing what the penetration rates are for the specific versions of the various mobile web browsers.

I've looked here - http://gs.statcounter.com/#mobile_browser-US-monthly-201105-201107 - which is a good start, but I'd really like to know what the numbers are for the specific versions of each browser - especially Blackberry, as they are so different.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've found so far:

For Android:
http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

For Blackberry (from March 2011, best I could find):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868567/what-market-share-do-each-of-the-blackberry-models-have

Answer (score 0):

Where? whole world? certain country? I don't think below can give you that much detail but,

try Admob's mobile metrics http://metrics.admob.com but last update was last year.

or

try Millenial media's S.M.A.R.T http://www.millennialmedia.com/research/smart/

or

InMobi's Network Report http://www.inmobi.com/research/

Comment: Thanks, but again couldn't find any version specific info on those sites.

Answer (score 0):

From Peter-Paul Koch's Quirksmode, [Mobile Browser Statistics](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2011/08/q2_2011_mobile.html).

Comment: That's good, but doesn't help me with knowing which versions of the mobile browsers are still relevant.  I.E. which Blackberry versions make up that %?